# Talend + lookup

Tags: lookup, talend

I'm starting to learn Talend and I'm facing this problem: I need to compare the column "Departamento" from the excel (input) with my static table db "Departamento" (input) in order to obtain IdDepartmento and insert it into the table Direccion(output)

[image: tMap]

[image: Job]

How may I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- InputA: Excel file
- InputB: DB table
- OutputC: DB Table

Job Graph:

```
Input A ---+
           |
           +---- tMap ---- Output
           |
Input B ---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below approach-
Input1: Excel file
Input2: DB table
Output: DB Table

Join input1 and input2 with a tMap. Make sure input2 becomes lookup flow and input1 as main flow. Then apply below settings.
1) compare Departamento & description.
2) set join type as left outer join 
3) Fetch IdDepartmento 
now connect the output flow to your DB output component.

Comment: Please add code snippet for your explanation. Or add this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by this you must have got your solution.

Well the Query you have written must have given Error... because it does not know what row4.somefield is. It only takes variables at the component and it does not look like variable so far.

Anyway here is how you can achieve your target
1)excel input as main
2)dbinput as lookup and connect it to tMap component and make the Innerjoin base on the condition that you have written as sql

configure your output and what field you need and 3) Connect the component to the DBoutput component...and here you get the result.

Plz put your commemnts.

Answer (score 0):

In the output filter editor inside tmap you can actually specify condition between lookup and main table something like this "row1.yourcolumname=row2.yourcolumnname" where row1 is your main table and row2 is your lookup table.